# Resuming an activity in android from notification

Tags: android, android-activity, resume

I'm developing an android application, and in one activity, when the user presses the HOME button, a notification appears. Upon pressing the notification the activity would resume from where it left off. The problem is that the activity is recreated each time. Upon pressing the notification `onDestroy()` and then `onCreate()` is called. But say if I reopen the activity through the "Recent apps" it resumes successfully.

This question has been asked before on stackoverflow and I have tried the answers provided and none of them seem to work. The API that I'm using is the latest 4.4. The options I have tried are:

- Playing around with the Intent flags

`intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`

- Setting the activity to `singleInstance` and `singleTask`

How can I mimic the intent that is sent when I open my activity through 'Recent apps'?

EDIT: One more caveat that might be important. There's 3 activities in my program A B C.  When clicking on the launcher icon activity A is first started. The notification is created only when going from activity C to Home. I'm trying to resume activity C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

I was debugging the application through LogCat and looking at the intents that were being generated by the ActivityManager. Whenever I was changing the flags of the Intent, I wouldn't see the change in LogCat. So

`02-12 11:26:39.586: I/ActivityManager(766): START u0 {flg=0x1000c000 cmp=com.example.app/.controllers.Activity3 bnds=[0,153][1080,345]} from pid -1`

Changing the Intent flags didn't change the flg variable in the log. Apart from this, the notification image was staying in the Status bar, my app wasn't destroying it. What I did was add the `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` flag to the PendingIntent I was sending:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

So the problem was an incorrect PendingIntent that I must have created before, that was never being removed. Now I'm able to resume the activity by clicking the notification. Hope this helps someone that might have a similar issue.